# pjsip TLS connect() error: [code=70006]: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND) on Mac but no reason specified

Tags: c++, ssl, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

Getting TLS connect() error: [code=70006]: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND) with pjsua(2) with my program and pjsip integrated. The error does not seem to describe what is actually wrong. What's actually going on?? What's not found?

The following is true:

- Same code works on Windows
- Same program will work on the Mac developed (both El Capitan and Mojave dev machines)
- Same program throws the full error below on another Mac when packaged in single .app
- Server (songbird.sip.server, not actual server name) is reachable, Asterisk PBX, does not show any connexion attempts in the SIP debug, can ping from device
- No firewall is active on the Mac devices

```
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.184699: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]            pjsua_acc.c Acc 0: setting registration..
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.186322: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]     tlsc0x7f90d706d428 TLS client transport created
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.186473: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]     tlsc0x7f90d706d428 TLS transport 192.168.86.95:62615 is connecting to songbird.sip.server:5061...
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.186550: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]            pjsua_acc.c Contact for acc 0 updated: <sip:2e8f04b6-dc64-4fdf-8e8b-5e034246df4d@192.168.86.95:62615;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000062a2dee5>"
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.188984: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]           pjsua_core.c TX 774 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=36644 (tdta0x7f90d58018a8) to TLS www.xxx.yyy.zzz:5061:
REGISTER sip:songbird.sip.server SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.86.95:62615;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjB75FE879-DFF6-4FC2-AA8A-C1A89D5E2496;alias
Route: <sip:songbird.sip.server;transport=tls;lr>
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:2e8f04b6-dc64-4fdf-8e8b-5e034246df4d@songbird.sip.server>;tag=9FBBCCE5-7560-4737-B33E-4FFEE66BEC8C
To: <sip:2e8f04b6-dc64-4fdf-8e8b-5e034246df4d@songbird.sip.server>
Call-ID: C8D621A4-E35F-4D18-9373-9BC10CE1DC02
CSeq: 36644 REGISTER
Supported: outbound, path
Contact: <sip:2e8f04b6-dc64-4fdf-8e8b-5e034246df4d@192.168.86.95:62615;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000062a2dee5>"
Expires: 300
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.189086: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]            pjsua_acc.c Acc 0: Registration sent
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201446: <info> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]     tlsc0x7f90d706d428 TLS connect() error: [code=70006]: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND)
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201536: <info> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]      tsx0x7f90d78038a8 Temporary failure in sending Request msg REGISTER/cseq=36644 (tdta0x7f90d58018a8), will try next server: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND)
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201614: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]           pjsua_core.c TX 774 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=36644 (tdta0x7f90d58018a8) to TLS www.xxx.yyy.zzz:5061:
REGISTER sip:songbird.sip.server SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.86.95:62615;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjB75FE879-DFF6-4FC2-AA8A-C1A89D5E2496;alias
Route: <sip:songbird.sip.server;transport=tls;lr>
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:2e8f04b6-dc64-4fdf-8e8b-5e034246df4d@songbird.sip.server>;tag=9FBBCCE5-7560-4737-B33E-4FFEE66BEC8C
To: <sip:2e8f04b6-dc64-4fdf-8e8b-5e034246df4d@songbird.sip.server>
Call-ID: C8D621A4-E35F-4D18-9373-9BC10CE1DC02
CSeq: 36644 REGISTER
Supported: outbound, path
Contact: <sip:2e8f04b6-dc64-4fdf-8e8b-5e034246df4d@192.168.86.95:62615;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000062a2dee5>"
Expires: 300
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201729: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]            pjsua_acc.c Disconnected notification for transport tlsc0x7f90d706d428
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201781: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]        sip_transport.c Transport tlsc0x7f90d706d428 shutting down, force=0
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201839: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]            pjsua_acc.c Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 0 in 309 seconds..
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201891: <info> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]      tsx0x7f90d78038a8 Failed to send Request msg REGISTER/cseq=36644 (tdta0x7f90d58018a8)! err=70006 (Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND))
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201928: <warn> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]            pjsua_acc.c SIP registration failed, status=503 (Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND))
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.201957: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]            pjsua_acc.c Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 0 in 306 seconds..
2019-09-26, 13:59:38.202053: <debug> (0x0000700002164000) [PJSIP]     tlsc0x7f90d706d428 TLS transport destroyed with reason 70006: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gnuTLS for your TLS backend? If so, the error correspond to GNUTLS_E_NO_CERTIFICATE_FOUND. Perhaps you could check your cerificate setup?

Comment: The certificate setup as in what ciphers it supports?

Comment: Here are some suggestions:
1. Disable TlsConfig::verifyServer if you have enabled it. The library will disconnect the connection if it fails to verify the server. If you disable it, you can add your own verification method to the server from Endpoint::onTransportState()

2. Check if you need to specify cerificate to the client. See TlsConfig fields (e.g: CaListFile, certFile, privKeyFile, password)

3. If the above fails, try changing the ssl backend to OpenSSL